# Change map visualization symbols

Tags: powerbi

I try to change the bubbles symbols of Map Visualization to an other format symbol but , i can't do it .

Can u help me to resolve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRdky.png)

Thank you!

I tried to search on internet and in the application .